# How to run dataiku as a docker container?

Tags: docker, automl

I am trying to run dataiku image as a docker container.
The docker image of dataiku is https://hub.docker.com/r/dataiku/dss
The setup runs fine, but when signing for the free edition of dataiku, I need to login through the username password.

I have tried running the dataiku image interactive mode, but does not help me in that case.

Can someone help me in how to run dataiku on docker?

Answer (score 0):

admin/admin is the default username/password.

Comment: How to enter it in a running container?

Comment: i thought you are unable to login to locally running Dataiku container UI. can you elaborate your problem. what is that thing you are unable to do even if you are running your container successfully.

Comment: My conntainer is running fine. I can even access the console on localhost:10000. I am not able to figure out where to login as the home page asks for the dss certificate and the container does not asks for the username password. I am stuck with the home pafe and dont know how to proceed.